# BadMethodCallException:Method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AdminLoginController::showLoginForm does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

[image]what could be the problem with code.
Method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AdminLoginController::showLoginForm does not exist.
below is my AdminLoginController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
public function showLoginForm()
    {
      return view('auth.admin-login');
    }
```

this is my web.php

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
  Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
  Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
  Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
  Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');
});
```

Comment: If you're auth folder is in Admin folder then it should be this `Admin\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm`, Did you create this controller `AdminLoginController` ?

Comment: I dont have admin folder .my admin-login.blade.php is inside auth folder.yes i have AdminLoginController that contain this file  ````public function showLoginForm()
    {
      return view('auth.admin-login');
    }````

Comment: I'm not talking about resource files, can you please show us you're controller structure ?

Comment: i have added it in my question can you check now

Comment: Can you send screenshot of your class from the top ? Also are you overriding laravel auth controllers ?

Comment: @ViperTecPro i have added the screenshot

Comment: Alright i think it's cache problem now try following commands `composer dumpa`, `php artisan config:Cache`, `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: @ViperTecPro thanks it worked God bless you .

Comment: Please upvote and marked as solved

Comment: Your acknowledgment on this question and  answer is required, please do revert back if you've resolved this question and marked answer as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is with the namespace

```
Route::group([
  'namespace'  => 'Admin',
  'as'         => 'admin.',
  'prefix'     => 'admin'
],function(){
    // Authentication Routes...
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
});
```

[image]

Now in case if you're using your custom Login controller, don't forget to mention correct namespace on the top of the file something like this,

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth;
```

After making changes, please type following commands :-

```
composer dumpa // also known as composer dump-autoload
php artisan config:cache
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: can you check my code again i have add the namespace ````namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;````